# Vue deployment with Dokku

Tags: docker, vue.js, heroku, dokku

My project is working and build correctly in local, in `development` or `production`, but when I try to push to my DigitalOcean Ubuntu server through Dokku it crashes

```
# server.js at the root
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const serveStatic = require('serve-static');

let app = express();
app.use(serveStatic(__dirname + "/dist"));

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Listening on port ' + port)
});
```

```
# current vue.config.js
# note that it had no option originally but changing it didn't solve the problem
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  publicPath: '/',
  configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/')
      }
    }
  },
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        data: `@import "src/assets/styles/helpers.scss";`
      }
    }
  },
  pluginOptions: {}
}
```

And here's the crash

```
-  Building for production...

ERROR  Failed to compile with 24 errors2:31:56 PM

These dependencies were not found:

* @/components/Errors/DefaultError in ./src/main.js
* @/components/Layouts/ChatLayout in ./src/main.js
* @/components/Layouts/DashboardLayout in ./src/main.js
* @/components/Layouts/DefaultLayout in ./src/main.js
* @/mixins/CurrentIdentityMixin in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/ConnectRouting.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&, ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/Chat/Events/File.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& and 16 others
* @/mixins/LayoutMixin in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&, ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/ConnectRouting.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
```

This is very strange, it's as `@` wasn't recognised as shortcut in Vue, but I don't really know how to fix it. I think setting everything with relative path manually would solve the issue (it worked at least for the layouts when I tried); it's not really a fix though, just a bad workaround.

I also changed a few times the node / npm version, without success. Here's the `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "askalfred-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "generate": "graphql-codegen",
    "postinstall": "npm run build",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@sentry/browser": "^5.4.0",
    "@sentry/integrations": "^5.4.0",
    "actioncable": "^5.2.2-1",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.1.20",
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.3.5",
    "apollo-client": "^2.4.2",
    "apollo-link": "^1.2.3",
    "apollo-link-http": "^1.5.5",
    "apollo-upload-client": "^10.0.1",
    "autosize": "^4.0.2",
    "epic-spinners": "^1.1.0",
    "flexboxgrid": "^6.3.1",
    "graphql": "^14.1",
    "graphql-ruby-client": "^1.6.3",
    "lowdb": "^1.0.0",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "shortid": "^2.2.8",
    "showdown": "^1.9.0",
    "tingle.js": "^0.14.0",
    "typescript": "^3.4.5",
    "v-mask": "^1.3.3",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-analytics": "^5.17.0",
    "vue-apollo": "3.0.0-beta.25",
    "vue-notification": "^1.3.16",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.4",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@graphql-codegen/cli": "^1.2.0",
    "@graphql-codegen/fragment-matcher": "^1.2.0",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript": "^1.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.5.1",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint": "^5.15.3",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^12.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.2.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.9.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "serve-static": "^1.14.1",
    "vue-cli-plugin-apollo": "^0.20.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.21"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "v11.11.0",
    "npm": "6.7.0"
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**Somewhat working solution**

For anyone which would end up in the same situation, I believe most tutorial about Dokku / VueJS are out of date, and lead to stupid mistakes, or at the very least does not tackle the deployment correctly with the newer versions. After several hours I figured:

```
"postinstall": "npm run build",
```

I removed this from the `package.json` and now it deploys without problem. I'm unsure if the success was due to  removing the `/dist` from `.gitignore` in my project and building it locally, or if the something happens while it's deployed, but it's enough in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Better way imo.

Just create an empty file called exactly ".static" on the root folder of the project.

Then on the dokku server run:

dokku config:set yourappname NGINX_ROOT=dist BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/dokku/buildpack-nginx

The dist folder needs to be commited (remove it from .gitignore).

Then run "git push dokku master".